# Photo information in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, photos

How can I see in Windows Explorer listing if an image is RGB, CMYK, YCbCr, etc.

I tried with all available columns, but none seems to give me that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows 7, right click on the picture and select Properties. There is a tab with "details", scroll down to "Color Representation" and you will find your answer.

[image]

Comment: thanks, what about same info in file list in windows explorer. I need it to filter large number of photos.